# sed not replacing characters in Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, character

I'm trying to write a shell script that replaces every character that isn't an uppercase letter. The first argument is a character (this will replace the others), while the other arguments are file names. When I try the Sed command in the terminal, it works just fine, however in my script it simply prints out every line except for those that start with the given character. (I want the results on stdout.)

```
for i in "${@:2}"
do
   if [ -f $i ]
   then
      sed "s/[^A-Z]/${1}/g" $i
   else
      echo "$i does not exist"
   fi
done
```

Comment: It's just not possible for the script you posted to behave as you say it does. There's something else going on unrelated to the contents of that script.

Comment: I checked it again, and it works without a problem. Thank you everyone for the help, and sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace :

```
sed "s/[^A-Z]/${1}/g" $i
```

by :

```
sed -e "s/[^A-Z]/${1}/g" $i
```

To replace every letters to uppercase you can do :

```
sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\U\1/' $i
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read properly the question; I'll remove my answer !

Comment: No, still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your script using f1,f2,f3 with the same contents, are you sure it's not working?

```
line1 Something Something Something
line2 Something Something Something
line3 Something Something Something

./input_test.sh x f1 f2 f3
xxxxxxSxxxxxxxxxSxxxxxxxxxSxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxSxxxxxxxxxSxxxxxxxxxSxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxSxxxxxxxxxSxxxxxxxxxSxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxSxxxxxxxxxSxxxxxxxxxSxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxSxxxxxxxxxSxxxxxxxxxSxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxSxxxxxxxxxSxxxxxxxxxSxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxSxxxxxxxxxSxxxxxxxxxSxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxSxxxxxxxxxSxxxxxxxxxSxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxSxxxxxxxxxSxxxxxxxxxSxxxxxxxx
```